# Running python manage.py command from django with arguments

Tags: database, django, backup, celery, django-postgresql

I have the command :

```
./manage.py dbbackup --clean --compress
```

provided by the django-dbbackup app which performs a backup of my PostgreSQL database to Amazon S3. I am trying to run this command inside a django celery task run daily.

When I run:

> from django.core.management import call_command
>   call_command('dbbackup --clean --compress', interactive=False)

I am getting an exception because of the clean and compress arguments.

Any ideas on how I can run this command?

Answer (score 1):

I magically found that running:

```
call_command('dbbackup', clean=True, compress=True, interactive=False)
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give arguments as separate strings:

```
call_command('dbbackup', '--clean', '--compress', interactive=False)
```